# How to capture a SQL query into a table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to capture a SQL query results into a table.  The query works fine without the code around it to capture it into the table but I get syntax errors near ')'.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select *
Into #TempTable
From    
    (Select 
        SUM ([Total Messages]) as WTMT ,
        SUM ([Messages Below Threshold]) as [Weekly Messages Below Threshold],
        SUM ([Average Time (Sec )]) as [Weekly Average Delivery Time],
        (SUM ([Total Messages])- SUM ([Messages below threshold]))
        As [Weekly Messages Above Threshold]
    from [Weekly Mail Delivery Times ByServer])
```

Comment: Did you try - ah - pasting it into SSMS and formatting it over multiple lines so that the missing ) becomes obvious?

Comment: See Conrad Lotz's answer. You need to give an alias to the subquery result set.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding an alias to the query:

> SELECT  * INTO    #TempTable FROM    ( SELECT    SUM([Total Messages])
>   AS WTMT ,
>                       SUM([Messages Below Threshold]) AS [Weekly Messages Below Threshold] ,
>                       SUM([Average Time (Sec )]) AS [Weekly Average Delivery Time] ,
>                       ( SUM([Total Messages]) - SUM([Messages below threshold]) ) AS [Weekly Messages Above Threshold]
>             FROM      [Weekly Mail Delivery Times ByServer]
>           ) AS t

Comment: Yup, can't do a subquery without giving an alias to the resulting set.

Answer (score 2):

Either one of these will work

```
Select  * 
Into    #TempTable 
From    (
        Select  SUM ([Total Messages]) as WTMT , 
                SUM ([Messages Below Threshold]) as [Weekly Messages Below Threshold], 
                SUM ([Average Time (Sec )]) as [Weekly Average Delivery Time], 
                (SUM ([Total Messages])- SUM ([Messages below threshold])) As [Weekly Messages Above Threshold] 
        from    [Weekly Mail Delivery Times ByServer]
        ) As X
```

or

```
Select  SUM ([Total Messages]) as WTMT , 
        SUM ([Messages Below Threshold]) as [Weekly Messages Below Threshold], 
        SUM ([Average Time (Sec )]) as [Weekly Average Delivery Time], 
        (SUM ([Total Messages])- SUM ([Messages below threshold])) As [Weekly Messages Above Threshold] 
Into    #TempTable 
from    [Weekly Mail Delivery Times ByServer]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your derived table needs an alias:

```
Select * Into #TempTable From
 (Select SUM ([Total Messages]) as WTMT , SUM ([Messages Below Threshold]) as [Weekly Messages Below Threshold], SUM ([Average Time (Sec )]) as [Weekly Average Delivery Time], (SUM ([Total Messages])- SUM ([Messages below threshold])) As [Weekly Messages Above Threshold] from [Weekly Mail Delivery Times ByServer]) q
```